# While in comparing value to array keys

Tags: php, optimization

Well I have a solution that looks:

```
<?php foreach($overdue_tasks as $task) { ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $task_url.'/'.$task->id; ?>" title="Przejdź do zadania">
    <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Spóźnione zadanie ID: <?php echo $task->id; ?>
    <?php
    foreach($overdue_days as $id => $days)
    {
        if($task->id == $id)
        {
            echo "dni spóźnienia: ".Arr::get($overdue_days, $task->id);
        }
    }
    ?>
    </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

But I have a question, can I replace second `if` with some sort of `while` for better optimization? I need to compare each `id` of first loop to keys in second array and print value of second array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

much better

```
if (array_key_exists($task->id, $overdue_days)) {
    echo "dni spóźnienia: ".Arr::get($overdue_days, $task->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($overdue_days as $id => $days)
{
  if($task->id == $id)
  {
    echo "dni spóźnienia: ".Arr::get($overdue_days, $task->id);
  }
}
```

could be replaced per:

```
if(key_exists($task->id, $overdue_days)) {
   echo "dni spóźnienia: ".Arr::get($overdue_days, $task->id); // == $overdue_days[$task->id]
}
```